# Using only HTML, how to left align all text and right align all numbers in a HTML table?

Tags: python, html, replace

Suppose I have the following HTML table:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>More data</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> -1234.1596 </td>
    <td> -0.15 </td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 3714.8146 </td>
    <td>0.48</td>
    <td>Centro comercial </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This HTML snippet looks like this:

[image]

However, I need to find a way of left-aligning all text and right-aligning all numbers. Note that this is just a minimal reproducible example. I generate giant tables in Python and need to strategically align everything without knowing exactly what the table looks like. For example, in Python I currently have

`table.replace("<th>", "<th align=\"left\" >")`

but this also left-aligns the number cells.

Comment: If you `generate giant tables in Python` why wouldn't you generate the table directly with the corresponding headers correct align attribute?

Comment: I take output from a Python library that just returns everything in a single giant string

Comment: @Xtiaan Can you share about the library that generates this? There may be a better way to handle your case.

Comment: Why do you have an HTML only requirement? 4 lines of CSS can handle your issue without bloating your table enormously

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using python to transform your string, you can use `re.sub` with a custom replacement function that returns a different string depending on whether the value in the cell is numeric or not (I assume you want to work on the cells, not the headers, but if not it will be easy to adapt or complete the code):

```
import re

def align_replace(m):
    numeric = re.match(r'[+-]?\d+(.[\d+])?', m.group(2).strip())
    if numeric:
        return f'<td align="right">{m.group(2)}'
    else:
        return f'<td align="left">{m.group(2)}'

aligned_table = re.sub(r'(<td>)([^<]+)', align_replace, table)
```

On your example string, this yields:

```
'<table>  <tr>    <th>Data</th>    <th>More data</th>    <th>Header 2</th>    <th>Header 3</th>    <th>Header 4</th>  </tr>  <tr>    <td align="right"> -1234.1596 </td>    <td align="right"> -0.15 </td>    <td align="left">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>    <td align="left">Maria Anders</td>    <td align="left">Germany</td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td align="right"> 3714.8146 </td>    <td align="right">0.48</td>    <td align="left">Centro comercial </td>    <td align="left">Francisco Chang</td>    <td align="left">Mexico</td>  </tr></table>'
```

Comment: I didn't catch the fact that he's only working on `th`, he probably thought that it was aligning all cells to the left because table data defaults to left alignment while table headers to center.

Answer (score 0):

You could first get a `tr` with data to check for text or numbers.

Something like parsing with BeautifulSoup, grabbing the `td` children of the first `tr`.

Then use that as a way to assign types to indexes.

Try to convert the first td's content to integer, if it fails, save 0 as text, if it succeeds save 0 as number.

Then based on that find the 0th th and assign an align attribute based on what you found on the tds.